# Como mostrar los 12 meses del año con un control calendar en wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un control de calendar, pero necesito que muestre los doce meses para trabajar con ese calendar, alguien sabe como hacerlo, gracias por su colaboración

Comment: que has intentado hacer? y que obtienes al hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

viendo que tu pregunta inicial se entendía muy diferente a la actualización actual, te dejo una idea de como pudieras hacerlo sin necesidad de librerías adicionales.

Usando un listado de `Calendar`, el XAML pudiera quedar algo asi:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCalendars}" Margin="5 10 5 5">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Calendar DisplayDateStart="{Binding StartDate}" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding EndDate}" DisplayMode="Month" DisplayModeChanged="Calendar_DisplayModeChanged"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Nota:** [WrapPanel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel?view=netframework-4.7.2) nos ayudará mantener los calendarios alineados a la izquierda, incluso si la ventana cambia su tamaño.

Donde `MyCalendars` seria un listado de objetos que guardarían la información de cada `Calendar`, la llamaremos `MyCalendar`. Dicha clase debería de tener al menos las dos propiedades a las que se les hace `Binding`, me refiero a `StartDate` & `EndDate`.

```
public DateTime StartDate
{
    get
    {
        return startDate;
    }
    set
    {
        startDate = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("StartDate");
    }
}

public DateTime EndDate
{
    get
    {
        return endDate;
    }
    set
    {
        endDate = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EndDate");
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Para que la GUI este actualizada, es necesario implementar la interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` en la clase `MyCalendar`.

> Te dejo un link al [repositorio](https://github.com/Tecnologer/WpfMultipleCalendar) del ejemplo completo.

Igual usaremos parte de la respuesta inicial, usando [DisplayMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaymode?view=netframework-4.7.2) con `Month` y el evento `DisplayModeChanged` nos permitirá asegurarnos de que el `Calendar` no cambie de modo.

```
private void Calendar_DisplayModeChanged(object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Calendar calObj = sender as Calendar;

    calObj.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Month;
}
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas tardes, lo que quiero lograr es algo como  el monthcalendar de windows form en que puedo indicar en cuantas columnas y filas puede visualizarse para seleccionar diversas fechas al mismo tiempo, esto es posible?

Comment: pues simplemente se me ocurre crear un listado de objetos `Calendar`

Comment: listo, te he colocado un ejemplo, espero que te sirva para una idea